# Protractor not able to sync with page

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to get a basic Protractor test working (with Jasmine). Protractor is installed, selenium is running, and the example from the Protractor documentation is working.

However, when I copy the contents of the tested website ("The Basics" example on angularjs.org) to a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/yfUQ8/2/), the test errors:

```
Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: {}
```

My test looks like this:

```
describe('angularjs homepage', function() {
  it('should greet the named user', function() {
    browser.get('http://fiddle.jshell.net/yfUQ8/2/show/'); // fails
    // browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org/'); // works

    element(by.model('yourName')).sendKeys('Julie');
    var greeting = element(by.binding('yourName'));
    expect(greeting.getText()).toEqual('Hello Julie!');
  });
});
```

When looking at the fiddle manually, everything seems to be working fine. Angular is bootstrapped using ng-app, and the test runs in 3 seconds (so it doesn't seem to be a timeout).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Protractor needs to find the element with ngapp to synchronize.  The default is 'body'.  In your jsfiddle, I see:

```
<body>
  <div ng-app>
```

If you set the rootEl property, your jsfiddle should work.

```
describe('angularjs homepage', function() {
  it('should greet the named user', function() {
    browser.get('http://fiddle.jshell.net/yfUQ8/2/show/');
    browser.rootEl = 'div';

    element(by.model('yourName')).sendKeys('Julie');
    var greeting = element(by.binding('yourName'));
    expect(greeting.getText()).toEqual('Hello Julie!');
  });
});
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for :) I couldn't find this in the docs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But for some reason, setting `browser.rootEl` to "div" didn't work for me. But when I moved `ng-app` to the body it did the job.

Comment: 'div' didn't work for me either. move ng-app to the body tag works for me.